# how do I fix an interrupt that fires multiple times on EXTI9-5?

Tags: c, interrupt, stm32

I'm working on an STM32F303CC. on this mcu I'm using 6 buttons as interrupts. 5 of these buttons are connected to EXTI15-10 and one to EXTI9-5. the buttons on EXTI15-10 are working perfectly fine. although, when I press the button on EXTI9-5 it fires an incredible amount of times (randomly somewhere between 1500 to 4000 times or so).

it clears the flag, and when there's a breakpoint added to the interrupt function it only fires one time.

I've tried to see if it was a hardware bounce, but there is no bouncing, as checked with an oscilloscope. also it has this problem with both falling and rising edge trigger detection.

I expect to fire the interrupt just one time after a press, instead, it fires a very high amount of times.

what could be the problem?

thanks in advance,
Ruben

GPIO config:

```
  /*Configure GPIO pins : BUTTON_6_Pin BUTTON_5_Pin BUTTON_4_Pin BUTTON_3_Pin 
                       BUTTON_2_Pin BUTTON_1_Pin BUTTON_7_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = BUTTON_6_Pin|BUTTON_5_Pin|BUTTON_4_Pin|BUTTON_3_Pin 
                          |BUTTON_2_Pin|BUTTON_1_Pin|BUTTON_7_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

HANDLER1:

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  /* EXTI line interrupt detected */
  if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_Pin) != RESET)
  {
    __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_Pin);
    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(GPIO_Pin);
  }
}
```

HANDLERS2:

```
    void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void)
        {
          /* USER CODE BE

GIN EXTI9_5_IRQn 0 */
    
      /* USER CODE END EXTI9_5_IRQn 0 */
      HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_8);
      /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI9_5_IRQn 1 */
    
      /* USER CODE END EXTI9_5_IRQn 1 */
    }
    
    /**
      * @brief This function handles EXTI line[15:10] interrupts.
      */
    void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void)
    {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI15_10_IRQn 0 */
    
      /* USER CODE END EXTI15_10_IRQn 0 */
      HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_10);
      HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_11);
      HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_12);
      HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_13);
      HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_14);
      HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_15);
      /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI15_10_IRQn 1 */
    
      /* USER CODE END EXTI15_10_IRQn 1 */
    }
```

Comment: How can we know what's wrong with the code if you don't show it?

Comment: Your scope might be providing enough line cap (10-15 pf) to hide the debouncing.

Comment: This code is quite incomplete. What are the `BUTTON_...` defines?

Comment: I think buttons are not good candidates to trigger interrupts because when they bounce (and they do) you end up with complicating simple things. Make a cyclic interrupt and poll the buttons there, with debouncing.

Answer (score 1):

> what could be the problem?

Have you considered that it may be caused by bounce?

> it clears the flag, and when there's a breakpoint added to the interrupt function it only fires one time.

To me this sounds like you need to debounce the button[1][2] or add analogue filtering.

Can you share the circuit diagram with us ?

.

[1] https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/switch-bounce-how-to-deal-with-it/

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_technology#Debouncing

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000Avee6r/interrupt-fires-multiple-times-on-exti95?t=1625236364014) from community.st.com says...

> Make sure it checks and clears the flag early in the routine, then do other things. There is a tail-chain issue if you clear it right before returning.

Since this is a timing/cache issue, increasing compiler optimizations can make the problem appear and stepping in the debugger can make the problem disappear. The HAL can mask the problem due to it's extra code (callbacks etc).

Some solutions:

- Insert a synchronization barrier (DSB) before leaving the ISR (mentioned [here](https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/tools/f/keil-forum/27967/external-irq-called-twice-depending-on-optimization-level) and [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/39305823443/))
- Clear the interrupt bit as early as possible ([here](https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/tools/f/keil-forum/27967/external-irq-called-twice-depending-on-optimization-level))
- Read/write another location ([here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/39305823443/))

I see the same issue on newer STM32H7 variants.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same thing when I use s software trigger, and that doesn't bounce.  If I chain interrupts, and trigger this from inside a higher priority interrupt, I get a single interrupt provided that I set then immediately clear the SWIER bit in the calling routine.
If instead I software trigger this from the main code, I can't set then clear the SWIER bit since the interrupt will occur before I can clear it.  I then get two calls, even if I repeatedly clear the SWIER bit and write a 1 to the PR bit in the handler.
I haven't found a solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).